# wordpressでorder=ASCでブログを表示できない。

Tags: wordpress

Wordpressでorder=ASCでブログを表示したいのですが、一回目のループではできますが、二回目のループではできません。記事が二つあるはずなのに一つしか表示されません。どうすればよいのか教えてください！よろしくお願い致します。

```
<?php

get_header(); ?>
<!-- site-content -->
<div class="site-content clearfix">

        <?php

        if (have_posts()):
            while (have_posts()): the_post();

            the_content();
            endwhile;
            else:
                echo '<p>No content found</p>';
         endif;

            //opinion posts loop begins here
            $testPosts = new WP_Query('cat=4&posts_per_page=2&orderby=title&order=ASC');

        if ($testPosts->have_posts()):
            while ($testPosts->have_posts()): 
                $testPosts->the_post(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php
            endwhile;
            else:
                echo '<p> No content found</p>';
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();

        echo 'i';

        //opinion posts loop begins here
            $newsPosts = new WP_Query('cat=9&posts_per_page=2&orderby=title&order=ASC');

        if ($newsPosts->have_posts()):
            while ($newsPosts->have_posts()): 
                $newsPosts->the_post(); ?>
            <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php
            endwhile;
            else:
                echo '<p> No content found</p>';
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>

</div><!-- /site-content -->
<?php get_footer();

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

最初の記事にタイトルがなかったので表示できませんでした。